WSUS in a disconnected environment importing newer updates
I have an environment where I have an online WSUS and a disconnected WSUS to update the computers on the disconnected networks. I recently followed the instructions, and it worked for the initial export/import and deployment of the updates.
My question is, after the initial import, how do I export/import newer updates without having to export/import all the older ones? I just want the deltas, the new updates to import but I was wanting to leave some of the older updates. Or is it designed to where I need to approve the new updates, run the server cleanup on the online WSUS to clean out the superseded ones, download the entire WSUS Content folder to the disconnected WSUS, then run the export/import to the disconnected WSUS again which might include some of the updates I already have imported? Should I overwrite the WSUS Content on the disconnected WSUS and the run the import again? If so, is there something I should do in the disconnected WSUS first, i.e. decline updates and then run the server cleanup?
Not every update gets superseded at the same time so being able to leave some of the other updates in there will be nice. I just wanted to confirm my thinking I will need to re-import some of the non-supersede updates that I want to keep.
